# Dual monitors on one screen in OSX Yosemite?

Tags: macos, video

I am seeking a way to keep a permanenent small window in the corner of the screen that can show video, while working on multiple desktops (TotalSpaces 2), without the window getting affected.

In the olden days before mission control and multiple desktops you could make a keep a small video window with "Float on top", to keep it semi permanently in the corner of the screen.

Does anyone know of a way to kind of make a part of the screen completely unhinged from the rest of desktop switching and hot corners?

Ideally i would be able to follow a video in the corner while switching between desktops, going fullscreen, entering hot corners, without the screen getting affected, and therefore be able to follow a video conference, a facechat or the like without losing sight of the other person.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the (Unix) X world this would be called "pinning" the window. Not sure if this will help in searching.